# How to reduce the gap in dotted underline link?

Tags: css, hyperlink

We have custom link with dotted underlined style.

[image: screenshot of gap]

How can I reduce the gap? Currently `padding: 0;` and `line-height` is not working.

Comment: how about using `border-spacing` and `border-bottom: 1px dotted white;`?

Comment: @BradChristie: `border-spacing` only works on tables, I think...

Comment: I think reducing the gap is only possible with a container element, as in http://jsfiddle.net/AZrJW/.

Comment: @minitech: You may be right, was just going through the intellisense looking for border*.

Comment: Also, in case anyone wants [an example to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/32HJL/) (although if the OP would do something similar, that would obviously be better). But padding/margin=0 and negative padding/margins have no effect. Not sure what will...

Comment: @sachleen [Here is my code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18730535/Untitled-1.png)

Comment: @user1978873 update your question with code so everyone can see it without having to dig through comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's something you could try that is a bit verbose, but if you really want to close the gap you could try adding an absolutely placed pseudo element that recreates the underline.

Here's my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tracyfu/RtQgh/).

Edit: Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32HJL/2/) updated by @bradchristie in the comments with a before and after using the OP's styles.

And here's my CSS:

```
a {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #f00;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a::after {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #f00;
  bottom: 3px;
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Agreed. I wish I had a more elegant solution. Best of luck!

Comment: Updated fiddle showing styles OP used (before and after): http://jsfiddle.net/32HJL/2/

Comment: @BradChristie Thanks for doing that :) It looks awesome. I'm embarrassed to say I was too lazy to reproduce the image.

Comment: @Will Thank you for the compliment. Improvements are always welcome! :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not using underline but a bottom border, the space is there to accommodate any text that might be there, including descenders and diacritic marks that might appear below the baseline. So you would need to defeat normal line formatting, e.g. by using trickery that reduces the content height, e.g. by setting

```
a { display: inline-block; line-height: 0.8; height: 0.8em; }
```